# Let $f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1, & \textrm{if } xy = 0 \\ xy, & \textrm{if } xy \neq 0 \end{cases}$

Tags: limits, continuity, partial-derivative

Then

(A) $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ exists

(B) $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ exists

(C) $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ does not exist

(D) $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ does not exists.

I feel it is discontinuous around the axis i.e. for any case where $x=0$ or $y=0$ and even plotting the graph shows this. So answer should be D right ? Can anyone give a better explanation ?

Comment: The answer is (B). This happens because partial derivatives care only about variations along the axes, but continuity cares about all points around (and close enough) to $x$. You have to verify both claims, however (using the definition of continuity and partial derivatives)!

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x_n,y_n)=\left(\frac1n,\frac1n\right)$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n,y_n)=(x,y)=(0,0)$ so $xy=0$ and $f(x,y)=1$, but $f(x_n,y_n)=\frac1{n^2}\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n,y_n)=0.$ It follows that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

However, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)= \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}h =\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)y-xy}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{x+hy}h=y, $ and similarly $ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y)=x.$